# OpenRefine split single column with repetitive values into well formated columns with headers

Tags: openrefine

I have a single column in OpenRefine like this:

```
 .TI
Localisation et dénomination :
Provenance des matériaux de monuments de Senlis

.DA
Date du cliché :
Janvier 1970

.R16N
Commune :
Senlis

.R17N
Département-Région-Pays :
Oise
Picardie
France

.R62N
Localisation plus précise dans l'édifice :
Cave


.R13
Datation de l'édifice :
Lutétien
Éocène
Paléogène

.MC
Mots-clés :
Pierre
Roche
Géologie
Caractérisation
Calcaire
Carrière
Liais
Liais de Senlis
Carrière souterraine
```

Data for each item begin with name of the tag, "Localisation...", "Date...", "Commune" etc.(the codes like .TI, .DA etc. are not important), followed by a value, and every tag or value are in successive rows, around ten thousands. I would like to have something like this, with tags as column headers:

```
Localisation et dénomination | Date du cliché | Commune | Département-Région-Pays | etc.
Provenance des matériaux de monuments de Senlis | Janvier 1970 | Senlis | Oise, Picardie, France | etc.
```

Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest approaching as follows:

- Import the data you have into OpenRefine in a single column (lets call it "Data")

  - Remove all the "codes" from your data:
  - Create a custom text facet using the GREL `value.startsWith(".").toString()`
  - Select "true" in that facet
  - Remove all the selected rows
  - Remove the facet

---

- Remove all the blank rows from your data

  - Facet by blank (null or empty)
  - Select "true" in that facet
  - Remove all the selected rows
  - Remove the facet

---

- Add a new column to your OpenRefine project using "Add column based on existing column" from the "Data" column

  - Use the GREL `if(value.endsWith(":"),value,"")`
  - Call the new column (for example) "Key"
  - Move the new Key column to be the first in the project
  - In the Key column use "Fill down"

---

- Remove the rows that have the "Key" in both the Key and Data columns

  - On the Data column, create a custom text facet with the GREL `value.endsWith(":").toString()`
  - Select "true" in that facet
  - Remove all the selected rows
  - Remove the facet

---

- Transpose the data based:

  - In the Key column select Transpose -> Columnize by key/value columns
  - Select "Key" as the Key column and "Data" as the Value column
  - Click OK

---

The result should be a table with each of your headings as the column headings, and the values listed underneath. Because some of your headings have multiple values (e.g. for a single "Localisation et dénomination :" you can have many "Département-Région-Pays :" etc. you may need to use the "Record" function in OpenRefine together with the "Join multi-valued cells" function to get the values into a single comma delimited cell

Comment: Thank you ! It works perfectly !
And I used the Record function as you mentionned for csv output.